# Google Maps DirectionService on iOS/Android SDK

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-maps

As the title said, I was trying to find a way to use the DirectionService on iOS and Android Google Maps SDK. I've found couple post talking about the similar solution; however, I need the direction service to take multiple waypoints instead of just directions between two points.  AFAIK, using javascript api is the only way to go...

I'm building an ionic app based on the javascript api, but I'm not very happy with the map performance on the mobile device.

Just for a reference, here's the piece of code that I need in my app:

```
var request = {
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    waypoints: waypoints,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    optimizeWaypoints: document.getElementById('optimize').checked,
    avoidHighways: document.getElementById('highways').checked,
    avoidTolls: document.getElementById('tolls').checked
};

directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
    if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
});
```

Any suggestion on how I can implement this in iOS/Android?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong this is a hybrid app that would use Javascript to display the maps on cross platform (Android/iOS). You can directly make use of the direction service as you are already doing. For your specific questions related to the `waypoints`, create an array where you store two attributes, `location` and `stopover`. This way you would have various waypoints in between the origin and destination.

```
{
  origin: "Chicago, IL",
  destination: "Los Angeles, CA",
  waypoints: [
    {
      location:"Joplin, MO",
      stopover:false
    },{
      location:"Oklahoma City, OK",
      stopover:true
    }],
  provideRouteAlternatives: false,
  travelMode: TravelMode.DRIVING,
  unitSystem: UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
}
```

Please refer to the official Google documentation on [Direction Service for Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)

Comment: you are totally correct, what I have now is a hybrid app and I would like to avoid that because the performance of google map is very bad on mobile devices. I really want to switch to, for example, google map iOS SDK and develop a native app instead. The only thing that keeps me from doing that is this direction service which is the whole point of my app.